# str[n]= "" for deleting string characters

Tags: python, string

Why this doesn't work for removing characters from strings in python?

```
  return str[n]= ""
```

and we are forced to use this:

```
  front = str[:n]   # up to but not including n
  back = str[n+1:]  # n+1 through end of string
  return front + back
```

The Problem:
Given a non-empty string and an `int n`, return a new string where the char at index `n` has been removed. The value of `n` will be a valid index of a char in the original string (i.e. `n` will be in the range `0..len(str)-1` inclusive).

```
missing_char('kitten', 1) → 'ktten'
missing_char('kitten', 0) → 'itten'
missing_char('kitten', 4) → 'kittn'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUuIo.png)

Comment: Because [strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/843953)

Comment: Also the pattern `return sequence[n] = ""` raises a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Even if it were possible in Python, from the homework assignment: "return a *new* string..." (emphasis mine). Not the same string with characters deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way of doing it is by iterating over all letters with the index via the enumerate method:

```
def remove_index_from(example_string):
    return "".join([letter for index,letter in enumerate(example_string) if index != index_to_remove])
```